# Regexp to replace a String with a number in the middle

Tags: regex

I'd like to replace a string with format

```
XXXXXXXXXXstart_N_endYYYYYYYYYY
```

(where N is a integer [can have multiple digits], and start, end are known fixed strings) removing the `start_N_end`.

So the result should be

```
XXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYY
```

A real example: I need to replace `Input_0_key` with `MyKey`

```
<input id="Input_0_key" name="Input_0_key" size="30" type="text">
```

Note: I need to make the replacement using a regexp, can't use a DOM parser or similar.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did s/Input_\d+_key/MyKey/ not work?

Comment: Explosion's solution contains serious flaw. You should never use even non-greedy `.`-matches on such data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s/Input.*?key/MyKey
```

The `.*?` will match as little as possible between `Input` and `key`.

Comment: It will match a great part of `id="Input" name="Input_0_key"` though.

Comment: Can't put code block in comment. Just take `id="Input" name="Input_0_key"` string and apply your regex to it. You'll see `id="MyKey"`.

Comment: @Artur press F12 and run this: `'<input id="Input_0_key" name="Input_0_key" size="30" type="text">'.replace(/Input.*?key/g, 'xyz')`

Comment: Your source data is too-well-formed. Test it on exactly `id="Input" name="Input_0_key"` and you'll see what's wrong with that regex.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using java which I suspect you are from your history:

```
str.replaceAll("(\"[^\"]*?)Input_\\d*_key([^\"]*\")","$1$2");
```

will take `"hiInput_12312312_keyhello"` and return `"hihello"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the " in the example close the string (syntax error). I've tried changing the preceding \\ with \ or \\\ but both options return the initial string

Answer (score 1):

try this in php:

```
$string = '<input id="Input_0_key" name="Input_0_key" size="30" type="text">';
$pattern = '~<input id="\K[^"]++(?=" name="Input_0_key" size="30" type="text">)~';
echo preg_replace($pattern, 'Youhou', $subject);
```

Answer (score 1):

As simple as `s/Input_\d+_key/MyKey/g`.